# Linq to datatable with unknown columns

Tags: c#, linq

I am having SQL query like this (will be parametrized once I make this work):

```
using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT MAGACINID, ROBAID, SUM(KOLICINA) AS GOD" + godina.ToString() + " FROM STAVKA WHERE VRDOK = 13 OR VRDOK = 15 GROUP BY MAGACINID, ROBAID ORDER BY ROBAID", con))
                        {
                            using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                DataTable tempDT = new DataTable();
                                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    da.Fill(dt);
                                    continue;
                                }

                                da.Fill(tempDT);

                                var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                                    .Join(tempDT.AsEnumerable(),
                                    x => new { field1 = x["MAGACINID"], field2 = x["ROBAID"] },
                                    y => new { field1 = y["MAGACINID"], field2 = y["ROBAID"] },
                                    (x, y) => new {
                                        x,
                                        addYear = y["GOD" + godina.ToString()]
                                    });

                                dt = LINQResultToDataTable(result);
                            }
                        }
```

And here is `LINQResultToDataTable()` method

```
        private DataTable LINQResultToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> Linqlist)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            PropertyInfo[] allColumns = null;

            if (Linqlist == null) return dt;

            foreach (T Record in Linqlist)
            {
                if (allColumns == null)
                {
                    allColumns = ((Type)Record.GetType()).GetProperties();

                    // Record at position 0 is whole object and needs to be broke into pieces
                    // Record at position 1 is new column

                    foreach (PropertyInfo GetProperty in allColumns)
                    {
                        Type colType = GetProperty.PropertyType;

                        if ((colType.IsGenericType) && (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                               == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                        {
                            colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        }

                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(GetProperty.Name, colType));
                    }
                }

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in allColumns)
                {
                    dr[pinfo.Name] = pinfo.GetValue(Record, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pinfo.GetValue
                           (Record, null);
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

First datatable fill is okay and it fills it with these columns:

```
MagacinID
RobaID
God2021
```

Now when I try to join new table using linq I should only add `God2020` as new column.
Problem is that when I am creating output of linq I cannot tell it to break `x` object into columns but I need to take it whole so linq result looks like this:

```
x (this one have ItemArray with all columns)
God2020
```

And new datatable looks same.

What I tried doing is inside `LINQResultToDataTable` method to take `0th` element of `Result` and break it into columns, add to datatable, add new one (1st element) and populate it (see comment in that method) but I am stuck and do not know how to do that. Anyone have any solution?

Edit: I made it not clear so here is more explanation.

I have `foreach` loop which loops through `5 databases` and inside that foreach loop is this code.

First database returns these columns

```
MagacinID
RobaID
God2021
```

Second

```
MagacinID
RobaID
God2020
```

Third

```
MagacinID
RobaID
God2019
```

Fourth

```
MagacinID
RobaID
God2018
```

Fifth

```
MagacinID
RobaID
God2017
```

I want all this merged into one datatable on columns `MagacinID AND RobaID` like this:

```
MagacinID
RobaID
God2021
God2020
God2019
God2018
God2017
```

Comment: I think your question is incomplete. In non relevant think to your question, personally I won't use linQ for this I will try to resolve this kind of problems on the DB layer.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Problem is that I am changing connection string (different databases) so I cannot do it on DB layer

Comment: You can do DB link. But I think you have to edit your question because is finishing in "like this:" and nothing more

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Sorry, corrected it.. It was just note.

Comment: I'm confused - you're filling a data table from your query, then projecting it to anonymous types, only to want to put it _back_ as a data table?

Comment: What, at a high level, are you actually trying to do? Join data from two DB and produce... a list of what? To do what with?

Comment: @DStanley Could you look at edit

Comment: @CaiusJard Take a look at edit

Comment: Genuinely, it feels like you should have these 5 datatables, set the correct PK on them all and then use [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=net-6.0#System_Data_DataTable_Merge_System_Data_DataTable_System_Boolean_System_Data_MissingSchemaAction_) method repeatedly to blend tables 2 - 5 into the first,  create one table, no LINQ

Comment: @CaiusJard Would like to but database is not managed by me but third company who is doing it like this. Table from which I am selecting have about 50 columns and one PK column which is ID with auto inc.

Comment: I meant using datatable Merge method (I linked it); it's nothing to do with DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Merge, I mean use the DataTable merge, which basically does something like a full outer join on declared PK fields in a datatable, and then makes the merged-into table the result of the join;

```
        var d1 = new DataTable();
        d1.Columns.Add("SomeId");
        d1.Columns.Add("Col1");

        d1.Rows.Add("ID1", "Col1Val1");
        d1.Rows.Add("ID2", "Col1Val2");
        d1.PrimaryKey = new[] { d1.Columns["SomeId"] };



        var d2 = new DataTable();
        d2.Columns.Add("SomeId");
        d2.Columns.Add("Col2");

        d2.Rows.Add("ID1", "Col2Val1");
        d2.Rows.Add("ID3", "Col2Val2");
        d2.PrimaryKey = new[] { d2.Columns["SomeId"] };



        var d3 = new DataTable();
        d3.Columns.Add("SomeId");
        d3.Columns.Add("Col3");

        d3.Rows.Add("ID2", "Col3Val1");
        d3.Rows.Add("ID3", "Col3Val2");
        d3.PrimaryKey = new[] { d3.Columns["SomeId"] };


        d1.Merge(d2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
        d1.Merge(d3, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
```

Here's what the above code leads to:

[image]

d1 started off with two columns, then during the first Merge it added in a third (Col2), and the values from d2's Col2 were put into d1's Col2, matching on the PK column (SomeId).

Then during the second Merge a fourth column was added to d1 (Col3), and the values out of Col3 in d3 copied into d1.

You'll notice that I deliberately made `d2` have different PK values to `d1`, so not only do new columns get added, but new rows get added too

No new rows were added by this second merge op (d1 already had an ID1, ID2 and ID3)

Comment: In my problem I do not have `PK` but `UNIQUE(MAGACINID, ROBAID)`

Comment: Oh i found out how to add multiple primary keys... I think it will solve my problem

Comment: `d2.PrimaryKey = new[] { d2.Columns["SomeId"], d2.Columns["SomeOtherId"] };`